# [orientdb]: get the current user when authenticating with tokens

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

How can i get the rid of the current user (OUser) via the binary api. I am using the inbuilt token based authentication. 
I would expect two approaches:

- a function like currentUserRID() or something. I looked in the documentation but found nothing.
- decrypting the token to unlock the userId/name. I tried this approach but couldn't manage to. I looked here: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2229 and also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/6sUfSAd4LXo

Answer (score 0):

I find your post just now, may be is too late but you can do like this:

---

```
OServer server = OServerMain.create(); //  for exemple

ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(BDDURL).open("admin","admin"); // admin is juste for this exemple

OTokenHandlerImpl handler = new OTokenHandlerImpl(server);

OToken tok = handler.parseWebToken(yourtoken);

OUser user =  tok.getUser(db);
```